# Can I use php and jquery in a facebook custom tab?

Tags: php, jquery, facebook

I am creating a custom facebook page using static HTML iframe tab.

Basically I am trying to publish on facebook a quiz I already have on my website. The user answers, and after the form is submitted it gots the results.

I know I can use javascripts, but am I allowed to load jquery library? And can I use somehow php code? I know there are some WYSIWYG applications that allow me to create forms, or even directly quiz contents.

However, it would be much easier and quicker for me if somehow I could just use my standard php coding from my website.

Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you are allowed to use jquery. It´s a simple iframe where you can use any JavaScript library. The only thing you need to be careful with are ads, Facebook does not allow any provider.
Obviously, you can also use PHP. What language you use on your server is totally up to you. Keep in mind that you need an SSL certificate for Page Apps though.

You should start at the very beginning and take a lot of time to browse the Facebook Docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/

Comment: I got it now. My question was pretty dumb as I can see now. I though that the iframe was on the index page defined in the static html app, I just didn´t realize that I can ifram whatever I want! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Facebook tabs simply present a page on your server within the Facebook frame, as an iframe. You can use any technology you'd use on your own server, because it **is** your own server.